# React Native Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

On writing my first RN application, I have got the below error message on executing the code,

"undefined is not a function (evaluating '_ConfigureStore2.default.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView())')"

ConfigureStore.js:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

var middlewares = applyMiddleware(thunk);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(reducers, initialState, middlewares);
}
```

CategoryContainer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import stores from '../stores/ConfigureStore';
import * as CategoryAction from '../actions/CategoryAction';

stores.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView());

class CategoryContainer extends Component {
}
```

CategoryAction.js:

```
import * as actionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';

export function categoryView() {
  const categories = ['CATEGORY1', 'CATEGORY2'];
  return {
      type: "CATEGORY_VIEW",
      categories: categories
  };
}
```

CategoryReducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
  categories:[],
}

export default function categoryReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CATEGORY_VIEW:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
              categories: action.categories
            });
    }
}
```

Even i tried the below approach in CategoryContainer.js, but still got the same error,

```
import { categoryView } from '../actions/CategoryAction';
stores.dispatch(categoryView());
```

Kindly assist to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On changing the ConfigureStore.js as below solves the issue.

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

/*var middlewares = applyMiddleware(thunk);
export default function configureStore(initialState) { //default is    undefined
  return createStore(reducers, initialState, middlewares);
}*/

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
export default store;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

#### CategoryAction.js

```
export default class CategoryAction {
    categoryView = () => {
        const categories = ['CATEGORY1', 'CATEGORY2'];
        return {
            type: "CATEGORY_VIEW",
            categories: categories
        };
    }
}
```

#### CategoryContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import stores from '../stores/ConfigureStore';
import CategoryAction from '../actions/CategoryAction';

stores.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView());

class CategoryContainer extends Component {
}
```

Comment: I tried the suggestd approach but still getting the same error 'undefined is not a function (evaluating '_ConfigureStore2.default.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView())')'

Comment: @univ Oh. Maybe the error is on the store then. Can you add that code?

Comment: I have update the post with additional code line. Hope this will help to analyse further.

Comment: @univ I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, but I believe you want a class called `ConfigureStore` in your ConfigureStore.js file. From there, you want a function called `dispatch` where you would put your logic. Your imports in the other classes should then be `import ConfigureStore from '../stores/ConfigureStore'`. See the `CategoryAction` class in my answer. It should follow a similar format to that.